# How to adapt function using comparables after switching to Dart 2.12

Tags: flutter, dart

I used to have a function:

```
extension IterableComparableExtensions<T extends Comparable> on Iterable<T> {
    Comparable get max {
        return this.reduce((Comparable value, Comparable element) =>
            value.compareTo(element) >= 0 ? value : element);
    }
}
```

Before I updated to Dart 2.12 this function was working fine. Now, AndroidStudio however complains:

```
The return type 'Comparable<dynamic>' isn't a 'T', as required by the closure's context.
```

I thought that most of the changes to Dart 2.12 were due to nullpointer issues that I don't see. What changed here and what's the new best practice?

Comment: @Dude : Replacing all the Comparable with Comparable<T> unfortunately isn't sufficient.

Comment: Can you show us a minimal reproducible example class with your problem?

Comment: Also, does it also fail if you do explicit tell Dart you want `dynamic`?: `Comparable<dynamic> get max { return this.reduce((Comparable<dynamic> value, Comparable<dynamic> element) => value.compareTo(element) >= 0 ? value : element); }`?

Answer (score 0):

I solved my issue. It seems that I now have to change it to:

```
extension IterableComparableExtensions<T extends Comparable> on Iterable<T> {

  T get max {
    return this.reduce((T value, T element) =>
        value.compareTo(element) >= 0 ? value : element);
  }
}
```